# use variable in sql trigger creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger dynamically and need to replace part of the create statement, in particular the database name that a join is done on.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_UseType_update] ON [dbo].[UseType] FOR UPDATE AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON 
  INSERT [dbo].[UseType]
  SELECT 'Updated', i.*
    FROM inserted
   INNER JOIN [(SELECT DB_NAME())].[dbo].[UseType] i ON inserted.[UseTypeID] = i.[UseTypeID]
END
```

I've tried this but obviously it just uses the text it doesn't actually evaluate SELECT DB_NAME(), is there a way to get it to evaluate this value.

I'm using sql 2005/8. We have a deployment tool that uses sqlcmd so a fallback will be to change the tool to take in variables that can be passed to sqlcmd but if I can reduce the amount of work and do it in the script itself (which is generated) that would be handy.

Comment: You don't need DB_NAME() because this would resolves to the same database containing the table UseType which has this trigger. And you write to the same table the trigger is on. What is the problem you *actually* want to solve?

Comment: Why include the database name at all? Shouldn't `dbo.UseType` give you the right table?

Comment: the trigger is in a different database to the database in the join

Comment: @daniel - updated my answer based on that comment

Comment: @Daniel - but you can only create a trigger in the current database you're using - in which case, `DB_NAME()` will resolve to that same database

Comment: Still no sense in it: On update of the local UseType table, read rows from UseType in another database that match the update, and INSERT into the local table? Is UseTypeID an IDENTITY? How can you be sure they'll match cross database?

Comment: this is an audit trigger, when data is changed in one database, basically copy that row into an audit row in another database with the same structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way would be to use dynamic sql.

There's no other way to parameterize database names or table names.

That being said, dynamically creating a trigger like this seems like a perilous idea.

The easiest way to do what you want will be something like:

```
USE MyDataBase

DECLARE @DB varchar(100) = 'MyOtherDatabaseThatIAmJoiningToInTheInsert'
DECLARE @SQL Varchar (MAX)

SET @SQL = '
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_UseType_update] ON [dbo].[UseType] FOR UPDATE AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON 
  INSERT [dbo].[UseType]
  SELECT ''Updated'', i.*
    FROM inserted
   INNER JOIN ' + @DB + '.[dbo].[UseType] i ON inserted.[UseTypeID] = i.[UseTypeID]
END'
```

[It's mandatory to read this before doing any dynamic sql code, though!](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: But DB_NAME() will be the same db that contains trigger and table.

Comment: @gbn - yep, that's why its pointless.  I'm assuming he wants to do this for multiple DBs, and will need something like `sp_msforeachdb`

Comment: yep, saw that, still a nonsense request though. A technically correct solution though.. but for what?

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially execute dynamic sql and load that into a temp table which in turn would be available to the trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_UseType_update] ON [dbo].[UseType]
    FOR UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        CREATE TABLE #t (userTypeId INT)
        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500) SET @sql = 'insert into #t select userTypeID from ' + DB_NAME() + '.dbo.UseType'
        EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql

        INSERT  [dbo].[UseType]
                SELECT  'Updated',
                        i.*
                FROM    inserted
                        INNER JOIN #t i ON inserted.[UseTypeID] = i.[UseTypeID]
    END
```

Comment: But it's the same database already! Read comments to the question

Comment: Agreed, I was simply answering how you might do it. Not whether it should be done or has any value.  There might be a similiar valid use for dynamic sql in a trigger.